# Multidimensional array loop not displaying the result for objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am getting the result from the SOAP client as an response. I just have to analyze the structure of the parameter and display the results accordingly. I have the following srucutre for SerialEquipment and i am getting the results peoperly for all the  parameters except the Esaco parameter. The Esaco parameter is an array object and it resides inside the SerialEquipment array. I am trying to fetch the response from Esaco array object but getting an error as Invalid arguments supplied for foreach. I am not understanding how to get the results for Esaco Parameter by looping properly.Just a small mistake i am doing in looping the array.

Code:

```
foreach($Serial as $key => $obj)
   {
        echo "<b>"."Serial Equipment=>" . $key . "</b>"."<br>";
        echo "Code=>". $obj->Code . "<br>";
        echo "Desc Short=>". $obj->Desc_Short . "<br>";
        echo "Desc Long=>". $obj->Desc_Long . "<br>";


        foreach($obj->Esaco as $key2 => $obj2)  
        {  
            if($obj2 === null){
        // doesn't contain Esaco
        break;
            }
            else{
              echo "<b>"."Esaco=>" . $key2 . "</b>"."<br>";                 
            echo "EsacoMainGroupCode=>". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupCode . "<br>";
            echo "EsacoMainGroupDesc=>". $obj2->EsacoMainGroupDesc . "<br>";
            echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupCode . "<br>";
            echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoSubGroupDesc . "<br>";
            echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoGroupCode . "<br>";
            echo "EsacoSubGroupCode=>".  $obj2->EsacoGroupDesc . "<br>";  
        }       
        }           
     }      

if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{   
     $vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
     $Serial=$vehicle['SerialEquipment'];        
     $VehicleFuel=$vehicle['VehicleFuel'];

        foreach($VehicleFuel as $key => $obj2)
        {           
            echo "Fuel Type=>". $obj2->Fuel_Type . "<br>";
            echo "Fuel Type Code=>". $obj2->Fuel_Type_Code . "<br>";
            echo "ECE_Unit=>". $obj2->ECE_Unit . "<br>"; 
            echo "ECE_In=>". $obj2->ECE_In . "<br>";     
            echo "ECE_Out=>". $obj2->ECE_Out . "<br>";
            echo "ECE_All=>". $obj2->ECE_All . "<br>";
            echo "ECE_CO2=>". $obj2->ECE_CO2 . "<br>";                       
        }   
}
```

This is my structure for SerialEquipment:
[image]

Comment: Show `var_dump` for `$vehicle` variable

Comment: please check the updated question for var_dump for SerialEquipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{
    $vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
    if(($serials = $vehicle['SerialEquipment']) === null){
        // doesn't contain SerialEquipment
        break;
    }

    foreach($serials as $serial){
        print "Code =>" . $serial->Code . "<br>";
        print "Desc Short =>" . $serial->Desc_Short . "<br>";

        //...

        foreach($serial->Esaco as $esaco){
            print "EsacoMainGroupCode =>" . $esaco->EsacoMainGroupCode. "<br>";
            print "EsacoMainGroupDesc =>" . $esaco->EsacoMainGroupDesc. "<br>";

            //...
        }
    }
}
```

And for the VehicleFuel:

```
if($parameter['aktion'] == 'getVehicle') 
{   
 $vehicle = getVehicleValuation();
 $Serial=$vehicle['SerialEquipment'];        
 $VehicleFuel=$vehicle['VehicleFuel'];

 $fuelType = $VehicleFuel->Fuel_Type;

 // if there is only going to be one VehicleFuel object Vehicle, then just do..
 echo "Fuel Type =>". fuelType->Fuel_Type . "<br>";
 echo "Fuel Type Code =>". $fuelType->Fuel_Type_Code . "<br>";

 // if there will be more than one, you will want to use a loop...

    foreach($fuelType as $obj)
    {           
        echo "Fuel Type=>". $obj->Fuel_Type . "<br>";
        echo "Fuel Type Code=>". $obj->Fuel_Type_Code . "<br>";
        echo "ECE_Unit=>". $obj->ECE_Unit . "<br>"; 
        echo "ECE_In=>". $obj->ECE_In . "<br>";     
        echo "ECE_Out=>". $obj->ECE_Out . "<br>";
        echo "ECE_All=>". $obj->ECE_All . "<br>";
        echo "ECE_CO2=>". $obj->ECE_CO2 . "<br>";                       
    }   
}
```

Comment: hello Alex it will not work because u have to loop inside loop in order to get all the values for Esaco...

Comment: Why do you? It's just an object inside an object? There are not more than one Esaco objects in the vehicle object, so there is no need to loop?

Comment: @user3844830 I have updated to better reflect your specific example

Comment: yes there are multiple values stored inside Esaco object so if we dont loop it, it will only show the first values for Esaco object...

Comment: @user3844830 Ah I see, there ARE potentially more than one Esaco object per SerialEquipment object. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Yes. Are you having problems?

Comment: please check the update question actually i have the same parameters VehicleFuel now like SerialEquipment and i am trying to fetch the values for this and i am getting null :( i have used the same logic for looping here too but dont know why not getting values :(

Comment: thanks Alex i tried in the same way looping but dont know why getting null values for VehicleFuel :(

Comment: Please do var_dump($VehicleFuel) and post the result in your question. Right after `$VehicleFuel=$vehicle['VehicleFuel'];`

Comment: thanks Alex because of var_dump i understood my mistake it has single value so no need to loop :) thank you so much... just last question in Esaco i am getting lots of null values those who dont have Serial Equipment and if i only want to show only those Esaco who dont have null values in that case do i need to you if close in for loop ?

Comment: I have updated my first answer to show that if it is null, break out of the function

Comment: As we used loop inside loop so those who has null values between those are also showing in Esacon and if we want to remove it then it will be done ..

Comment: Hi @Alex thank you but i dont want to check for SerialEquipment but i want to check the condition for Esaco. Please chechk the updated question . I have used this if condition to check whether Esacon values are empty or not and if it empty then dont want to show Esacon but not running :(

Answer (score 1):

The key `Esaco` is an object not an array. You should change your second foreach.

```
foreach($Serial as $key => $obj) {       
    echo "Serial Equipment=>" . $key . "<br>";
    echo "Code=>". $obj->Code . "<br>";
    echo "Desc Short=>". $obj->Desc_Short . "<br>";
    echo "Desc Long=>". $obj->Desc_Long . "<br>";  
    foreach($obj->Esaco as $key2 => $obj2) {
        echo $obj2;
        //...
    }           
}
```

Comment: thanks man its running now :) but i am getting as error in this loopforeach($obj->Esaco as $objects) saying invalig arguments supplied ?

Comment: After your edition. You can delete the thrid foreach.

Comment: No man when i removed third foreach its giving null values for Esaco :( Actually its showing the values only for those SerialEquipment those have only single time Esaco value. When there are multiple times Esaco values are coming its showing null there

Comment: I don't know what you are waiting for in Esaco object but I guess you can do it by yourself. It's the same behavior just loop on this object.